# Using variables in Logic Editor

Tags: game-engine

I'm quite new to Blender's game engine, but I'm trying to give it a go now.

My first try was to create a simple WASD keys character movement using the logic editor.

For that, I needed to set the Loc (location offset) in the motion actuator for each keypress, but since they would be all the same value, and I could want to change them at a later time, I wanted to use some kind of variable to control it, like "character_speed". I know this seems like an overkill, but I'm thinking ahead for keeping things organized for bigger projects.

Is there support for something like that? Maybe using python scripting or drivers?

Thank you!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with thinking ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add custom properties to any object in your scene to store simple data types like an integer,string,boolean,float or a timer variable.

The property sensor allow you to test their values , and the property actuator to affect to them new values.
the controller can do logic operations to combine tests and trigger different actuators.

for complex data types , like arrays and structures, you have to use a python script.

Comment: ok, I can create new properties in the object, but how do I call or access them in the logic editor? (or anywhere else, for that matter)

Comment: you add a [property sensor](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DXPOd.png) to test on their values, and a [property actuator](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uGzjV.png) to change their values

Comment: alright, but what is it possible to use properties like that in fields like those from motion actuators? http://i.imgur.com/Ilv1QNU.jpg

Comment: I don't think you can put them there without a script ,the properties can be access inside a script , and you can call the same function the actuators call with the values of your properties.

Comment: after some research, it really seems that scripting it away would be the only way, sadly. And just for the record, for simple things like character movement, it seems to be not worth the effort. It's much easier to just tweak it manually!

Comment: Hey, don't give up! It isn't that hard because I've done it and it wasn't too hard for me. I just can't remember what file I have it in. You can set a driver up quite easily and use that to drive the variable value for your speed. Drivers allow for variables and math functions. You just have to know the formula you want to use to calculate the speed.

Comment: there's no option to add driver on that field, at least on the UI... if only we could add a driver, it would be really easier to set up, of course!

Comment: Think about it - you are going to turn your pretty static behavior setup into a dynamic behavior. That is where you need to switch to scripting. The GUI is for simple (often used) cases only. When you need more complex things ... use Python. There is no need to clutter the GUI with lots of options.